# makefiles and their targets and dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a question on my mind regarding makefiles.

```
$(OBJECTS) : OBJEC/%.o : %.c
        gcc -c $< -o $@
```

I am unable to understand this rule.

Usually, there is only one target and its dependencies in a makefile rule, but there are 2 colons in the above piece of code.

I am unable to figure out which is the target and which is the dependency.
How does the code work?

Can anyone clear it up for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a static pattern rule. Have a look at [this section of GNU make's manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).
Basically, it states that the pattern `OBJEC/%.o : %.c` only applies to the targets listed in `$(OBJECTS)`.